# fs.copyFileSync("file1.txt", "file2.txt"); throwing an error

Tags: node.js, filesystems, file-copying, hyper

const fs = require ('fs');
fs.copyFileSync("file1.txt", "file2.txt");

//when i try to run this code on hyper it gives this error

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'file1.txt' -> 'file2.txt' ←[90m    at Object.copyFileSync (node:fs:2802:3)←[39m at Object. (C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\intro-to-node\index.js:2:4) ←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)←[39m ←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)←[39m ←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m ←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m ←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m ←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m { errno: ←[33m-4058←[39m, syscall: ←[32m'copyfile'←[39m, code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m, path: ←[32m'file1.txt'←[39m, dest: ←[32m'file2.txt'←[39m }

Answer (score 1):

This error tell you that file1.txt does not exists or is not readable.

Check if file1.txt exists. Check if your file1.txt is in the same directory than your node.js script, if not add a path before file1.txt.